# javascript filter on an array, return the object and its position within the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an array of objects like this:

```
camera = [{ id, idCam, lat, lng }]
```

I then have an id called idCamera which corresponds to the id of the object.

What I need to do is, get me back an `idCam` property and get me back where the following object is in the array.

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work, it returns the object but it doesn't return the key.

```
camera.filter((el, key) => {
 if (el.id === idCamera) return { idCam: el.idCam, key };
})
```

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: filter doesn't work like that.  The callback should return true if the item should be included, false if not.  Anything that gets true is included in the returned array.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Why do you need to select the item after a specific item? What should happen when the last item is selected?

Comment: To make sure we're using terms the same way, your array has a single object element with four properties on it, right? When you say "key", do you mean "index"? Arrays have indexes, and elements at those indexes. Objects have properties whose names are often referred to as keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'findIndex' function:

```
const index = camera.findIndex(el => el.id === idCamera);
const foundedCamera = {index: index, idCam: camera[index].idCam}
```

Comment: Simple and functional solution. `{index: index}` can be condensed in just `{index}`.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Array.findIndex` will returns you the index of the first element of the array that is matching the giving condition.

You can use this index to build the result that you seek.

Be carefull to handle the case where your array doesn't contains what you are looking for.

```js
const camera = [{
  id: 0,
  idCam: 42,
}, {
  id: 1,
  idCam: 69,
}];

const idCamera = 1;

function getCamValue(array, id)  {
  const index = camera.findIndex(x => x.id === idCamera);

  if (index === -1) {
    return -1;
  }

  return {
    index,
    idCam: camera[index].idCam,
  };
}


console.log(getCamValue(camera, idCamera));
```